# How to specify the memory location (fast/slow) of functions/vars in C99?

Tags: c, memory, c99

On many embedded architectures, it is possible to run the code or store data either into the internal RAM (fast access) or the external SDRAM (slow access).

On architectures like SHARC processors it is possible to define the memory region where a function will be linked to.

```
segment("seg_ext_dm32") void foo( void ); // External memory 32-bit location
```

Unfortunately the specifier `segment("seg_ext_dm32")` is not really ANSI and I cannot really omit it on my generic libraries that could be unit-tested on a different architecture (x86 for instance).

So I am looking for a more generic solution to classify my functions/variables to be stored either in a slow or a fast memory segment. Here is an example:

```
___slow void fft_configure( int parameter );
___fast void fft_tick();
```

What would be the most common way to do this?

Of course one easy way to do it is to add a general header file to my specific compiler to define what __slow or __fast would be:

In my main file:

```
#ifndef __slow
   #define __slow /* nothing */
#endif
#ifndef __fast
   #define __fast /* nothing */
#endif
```

In my compiler:

```
cc -D__slow=segment("seg_ext_dm32") -D__fast=segment("seg_dm32")
```

But I assume this is not the best solution.

Comment: The solution you want to implement is not a bad one, you shouldn't call these qualifiers `__fast` and `__slow` though, as names beginning with an underscore are reserved by the C language.

Comment: Generally, you are not going to be able to avoid defining such a macro, as the C standards neither provide a way to mark a variable as being in a certain segment, nor do they have the concept of a “segment” at all.

Comment: @FUZxxl you said `__` mangled names are reserved by the C language. What is about `_` or `___`? I am looking for a prefix that would not be found either in my code or in the C libraries.

Comment: This depends on the compiler and is far too broad for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @nowox: Please do some research for yourself. There is already enough information about reserved pre- and suffixes. Start with the standard. Note that `___` (three underscores) does start with two underscores, so .. well I'll leave that as a minor homework.

Comment: the question is about how to place specific items in specific locations in the address space.    The easiest way (especially for an embedded system) is to write a 'linker command' file and direct the linker to that file.  Then within the C code use #pragma's to direct specific items (right down to individual data) to specific sections.  Where those sections are defined in the linker command file.  Note: #pragma's are specific to each compiler and each underlying architecture.

Comment: @nowox there is no such prefix. A prefix is either reserved for the libc (and thus is possibly used by the libc) or it's not reserved (and thus possibly used by other code). In your particular use case, just use something like `FASTSEG` or `SLOWSEG` — short enough to not be tedious to type and unique enough not to appear in other people's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a LOT of ways to skin this cat, some more portable that others.

Probably the most portable method would be to segregate your functions into separate source files that are 'fast' or 'slow' (or even finer grain that that by putting one function group per file), and then have the linker descriptor file deal with sticking the segments where you want.  This keeps all the non-standard stuff out of your source files and puts it in one spot.

The linker descriptor file will have to be managed by the person using the library, **but they'll have to do that anyways** to properly locate any segments into 'fast' and 'slow' memory.   With this method, they'll just have to specify the right .o files in the load segment they've defined in the right place, rather than relying on the compiler to emit the catchall name you've chosen.

Comment: Quite often, you'd use a pre-made linker script with predefined segment names for slow and fast memory. In these cases, it's better to manually specify segment names than to fiddle around with the linker scripts you are not supposed to touch.

Comment: Except your pre-made linker script almost certainly isn't going to match vendor ABC's chosen section names.   If you're doing embedded work, you (or somebody in your organization) is dealing with the linker descriptor files.

Comment: Yeah, but changing the section names in a couple of macros is way easier than compiling different source code forms with different linker scripts (however this is going to work).

Comment: You don't have to do anything to the code except split it up into files that  you can direct into the segment in the linker descriptor file.   Specifying the file in the linker descriptor is as easy as adding `mycode_fast.o(.text)` in the right spot.  As a consumer of libraries in an embedded world, I prefer my vendor to not make assumptions that force me into using their methodology (which may conflict with another).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do.
I create an attribute that I can change depending on the compiler.
For my embedded application I use the following

```
#ifdef IS_EMBEDDED
  #define FAST_DATA  __attribute__ ((section ("fast_data")))
#else
  #define FAST_DATA /* DO NOTHING */
#endif
```

Then when I create global data that needs to be inside of the fast data section I apply the section location as follows.

```
char fastStack[1024*5] FAST_DATA;
```

Finally inside of my linker script.

```
MEMORY
{
   fastMemory : ORIGIN = 0x00000050, LENGTH = 0x0000ffff
   DDR3 : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0x8000000
   FLASH : ORIGIN = 0xC0000000, LENGTH = 0x02000000
}

...

.fast_data : {
    __fast_data_start = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(fast_data)
    . = ALIGN(8);   
    __fast_data_end = .;
} > fastMemory
...
```